# В каком месте следует корректно освободить память, выделенную под char** strlist?

Tags: c++, char, утечка-памяти

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
using namespace std;

char* sort_words(char* str)
{
char** strlist;
int delimcnt = 0;
int i;
for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) //считаем пробелы
    if (str[i] == ' ') delimcnt++;
        if(delimcnt == 0) {
            cout << "wrong input string";
                return '\0';
        }
strlist = new char*[delimcnt]; //заполняем массив строк
for (i = 0; i < delimcnt; i++) 
    strlist[i] = new char[20];
for (int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    if (str[i] == ' ') {
        if (j == 0) {
            strncpy(strlist[k], &str[j], i - j);
            strlist[k][i - j] = '\0';
            k++;
            j = i;
        }
        else {
            j++;
            strncpy(strlist[k], &str[j], i - j);
            strlist[k][i - j] = '\0';
            k++;
            j = i;
        }
    }
}
for (i = 0; i < delimcnt - 1; i++) //сортируем массив строк
    for (int j = i + 1; j < delimcnt; j++)
        if (strcmp(strlist[i], strlist[j])>0) {
            char* tmp = strlist[i];
            strlist[i] = strlist[j];
            strlist[j] = tmp;
        }
for (i = 0; i < delimcnt; i++) cout << strlist[i]<<" "; //выводим массив строк

}


int main()
{
char* stroka;
stroka = "here will be a memory leak "; // в конце добавляем пробел, чтоб отделить последнее слово
sort_words(stroka);
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Внутри `sort_words`, конечно, где же ещё?

Comment: Почему бы не использовать `std::string` и `std::vector` для уменьшения головной боли?

Comment: Делал для себя, в познавательных целях)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

После вывода дописать:

```
for (i = 0; i < delimcnt; i++) 
    delete[] strlist[i]; 
    delete[] strlist; код
```

Answer (score 0):

Там, где `strlist` гарантированно перестает использоваться, но как можно раньше (ближе к месту, где память выделялась).